# Segmentation Fault when refrencing vectors that changed size

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

So I initialize a vector within a main function, and pass that vector as a reference into a function where its size changes. Now, I would imagine that the initialized vector within the main would change in size, but its not. Am I just implementing this incorrectly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

void createImage(vector<vector<char> >& img){
    int cols, rows;
    std::cin >> rows >> cols;
    img.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        img.push_back(vector<char>(cols, 'O'));
}

void colorPixel(vector<vector<char> > &img){
    int xCoord, yCoord;
    char color;
    std::cin >> xCoord >> yCoord >> color;
    img[xCoord][yCoord] = color;
}

void printVector(vector<vector<char> > &img){
        for(int i = 0; i < img.size(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < img[i].size(); j++)
                std::cout << img[i][j];
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
}

int main(){

    char operation;
    
    while(std::cin >> operation){
        vector<vector<char> > myVector;
        if(operation == 'X')
            break;
        if(operation == 'I')
            createImage(myVector);
        if(operation == 'C')
            printVector(myVector);
        if(operation == 'L')
            colorPixel(myVector);
    }
}
```

Edit:
This is what is effectively happening. When you create the vector so I 5 5 which calls createImage(), that works, but it begins to fail when you L 4 4 P which calls colorPixel() at myVector[4][4].

If I were to initialize myVector in main to 250 250, then print will print all 250 lines, even after being changed in size (such as 4 4) in createImage().

In short, I believe, and know for sure, that the vector within main is not getting the hint that its size has changed, is there any fix for this?

Comment: How do you know that the size has not changed in `main`? You have no checks there.

Comment: What input makes it crash?

Comment: Each iteration of your loop creates a new vector ... Move the declaration _outside_ the loop.

Comment: When you create the vector so I 5 5 which calls createImage(), that works, but it begins to fail when you L 4 4 P which calls colorPixel() at myVector[4][4].

Comment: Your code has no range checking in `colorPixel`.  `printVector` assumes that the vector-of-vector is square, but this is not necessarily the case since the number of rows and columns are inputs.    (Those inputs are also not guarded against bad values like 0 or negative.)

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you for you original answer, it worked.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Alrighty, sorry. Wont do it again next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while(std::cin >> operation){
        vector<vector<char> > myVector;
```

The very first thing that happens in this `while` loop is that a new `myVector` gets created. This is, literally, what this says in C++.

When the end of the loop gets reached, this `myVector` gets destroyed. That's how C++ works: if you declare an object in a loop, or inside the `if` statement, the object gets destroyed when execution reaches the end of this scope.

So, when this `while` loop reaches this end, this `myVector` gets destroyed. It becomes no more. It will will be gone. It will ease to exist. It will be pining for the fjords. It will become an ex-myVector.

Then, the `while` loop's condition gets checked again, and if the condition still holds true, execution enters the `while` again, creating a new `myVector`, from scratch. It will have nothing to do, whatsoever, with the previous myVector, which is just a faint memory.

And the way to fix this is to declare this `myVector` ***before*** this loop, at the beginning of your `main`, so this `myVector` gets destroyed only when `main`, itself, finishes executing.

Comment: Almost literally parroting the classics here.